# Heroku run rake db:seed is broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, refinerycms

I'm using Refinery CMS with a custom engine and I'm not able to run `heroku rake db:seed`. It seems that this is causing my app to break in production.

Everything works fine locally, but I'm getting this output when I try to seed my database:

https://gist.github.com/f90b545dc85c44addffd

Any thoughts on what might be causing this. Here's my seeds.rb file:

```
(Refinery.i18n_enabled? ? Refinery::I18n.frontend_locales : [:en]).each do |lang|
  I18n.locale = lang

  if defined?(Refinery::User)
    Refinery::User.all.each do |user|
      if user.plugins.where(:name => 'refinerycms-projects').blank?
        user.plugins.create(:name => 'refinerycms-projects',
                            :position => (user.plugins.maximum(:position) || -1) +1)
      end
    end
  end

  url = "/projects"
  if defined?(Refinery::Page) && Refinery::Page.where(:link_url => url).empty?
    page = Refinery::Page.create(
      :title => 'Projects',
      :link_url => url,
      :deletable => false,
      :menu_match => "^#{url}(\/|\/.+?|)$"
    )
    Refinery::Pages.default_parts.each_with_index do |default_page_part, index|
      page.parts.create(:title => default_page_part, :body => nil, :position => index)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this I needed to specify `ruby '1.9.3'` in my gemfile. Apparently this is something related to deploying a Refinery CMS app to Heroku.

Once I deployed to heroku with `ruby '1.9.3'` in my gemfile I was able to do `heroku run rake db:seed` no problem.

More info on this here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/refinery-cms/bvGsot-wFxc